# check multiple items in list view

Tags: android, android-layout

I use an adapter to load a list view from a content provider. Each item in the list uses the below layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id ="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_chat"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have set the list item to allow multiple choice mode :

```
onCreate(){
    ...
    lv_chatMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_chat);
    lv_chatMessages.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv_chatMessages.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    ...
}
```

But at run time, i am not able to check any of the items in the list view. If i touch the box, the item just gets highlighted momentarily, but no check mark appears.

I can set a default for all the items if i add an attribute to the `CheckedTextView` :

```
android:checked="true"
```

How do i let the user change the check status of each item at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this link...

[CheckedTextView](http://blog.rochdev.com/2011/08/checkedtextview.html)

this may help you..

**[Edit by Faizal] :** 
Using the toggle() inside the onItemClickListener did the trick :

```
lv_chatMessages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) (((ViewGroup) arg1).findViewById(R.id.txt_chat));
            ctv.toggle();
        }
        });
```

Comment: The blog makes use of a seperate <CheckBox> element and code to store the checked status manually. But i want to use the existing behaviour of the <CheckedTextView> element, as used in the OP.

Comment: Thanks. that worked! I adapted the solution in the link, to the OP and edited your answer.

Comment: hmm wierd..my edit to your answer has disappeared. Added the edit again.

Answer (score 1):

can you add this into list items

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are using a custom adapter, you'll have to maintain the status of the checkbox in the `getView()` method of the custom adapter.

What you could probably do is to add another `Boolean` field to your `ArrayList` of Objects which you use to populate the adapter and check that value in the getView() method. to       Something like :

```
if(status) {
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
```

Also, update the `status` variable using `OnCheckedChangeListener()`.

This method will let you toggle status and also ensure that the checkbox status is maintained even when a list item goes out of the view.

Edit 1 : When not using a custom adapter. This is how I did it.

```
ListView rendererList;
ArrayList<String> friendlyNames;

friendlyNames = new ArrayList<String>();
rendererList = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rendererList);

ArrayAdapter rendererSelectionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,R.layout.custom_list_layout, friendlyNames);

rendererList.setAdapter(rendererSelectionAdapter);
rendererList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

custom_list_layout was the same layout which android provides, however, I had to make slight modifications so I copied the default file and edited.

here is the custom_list_layout :

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:background="@color/white"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_box_button_textsize" />
```

Comment: I am using a simple cursor adapter, not a custom adapter. I am looking to use the default behaviour provided by the framework rather than maintaining the checkbox status manually by defining a new checked status variable in my object.

Comment: Check EDIT 1. Added solution for simple adapter.

Comment: hmmm..I don't see what you did different from my OP.